# Como trocar o nome de uma coluna em um select no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, atributos

Estou fazendo um banco de dados para uma atividade da faculdade e foi pedido para mostrar a tabela alterando o nome dos atributos(colunas) para "`Nome do Cliente`" e "`Endereco do Cliente`". Como posso fazer isso?

**Exemplo:**

```
Tabela: nome         >       Saída: Nome do Cliente
Tabela: endereço     >       Saída: Endereço do Cliente
```

Comment: Você quer alterar o nome das colunas que são retornadas na sua consulta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apesar de sua pergunta não estar clara o suficiente, acredito que seja isso que você quer:

```
SELECT nome AS 'Nome do Cliente', endereço AS 'Endereco do Cliente' FROM clientes
```

O `AS` faz com que mude o nome da coluna exibido no `SELECT`, mas não confunda, ele só muda o nome na exibição do select, ele não altera a tabela.

Veja funcionando n [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e45e9/2/0).

Comment: boa, acho que é bem isso! Mas quem vai saber ...

Comment: É isso mesmo. Eu estava complicando algo simples.

Comment: @MateusBorges Poderia então marcar minha resposta como correta? Isso ajuda a manter a organização do site e também para quem tiver o mesmo problema no futuro.

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, porem ao fazer consulta os nomes das colunas devem ser envolvidos com ` (sinal de crase)

Veja os exemplos a seguir:

**O correto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O incorreto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]